# Error installing JDK: the keytool command requires a mounted proc fs (/proc). Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, proc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Oracle JDK 1.7 on Windows subsytem for Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and I get the following error:

```
the keytool command requires a mounted proc fs (/proc).
```

And the installation of Java fails with tons of errors:

```
the keytool command requires a mounted proc fs (/proc).
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64:
 openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64 depends on ca-certificates-java; however:
  Package ca-certificates-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up udev (204-5ubuntu20.19) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
 * udev requires devtmpfs support, not started
   ...fail!
```

This is the full log: http://pastebin.com/gycBK1L9

I have read that maybe it is related with the chroot and the initscripts but I can't get it working.

I need JDK in order to compile Android on my machine. Any help will be hightly appreciated.

Comment: Windows 10 has no /proc pseudo-filesystem, nor any implementation of it.

Open Bash, and try to cd to /proc, and see what is there.

Comment: Why are you trying to install an ancient version of Java?

Comment: Because Ubuntu 14.04 is ancient, and that is what they have in the repositories i guess.

Comment: @Gala I'm running Java 9 on Ubuntu 14.04 (a modern and supported operating system). Java **7** has been EOL since April of last year.

Comment: @Gala this is what I have in /proc `1  3893  954      cpuinfo      interrupts  mounts  self  sys     version
2  953   cmdline  filesystems  meminfo     net     stat  uptime`

Comment: Can you provide the info from "mount" command? Pastebin it.

Comment: Here you have it: http://pastebin.com/9nJwpc29

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Because that to compile Android 6 we need to use this version.

Comment: The Ubuntu on Windows feature is clearly not finishend, but a work in progress. What you are trying is probably simple not possible yet. Wait for updates, I am sure the proc file system will eventually implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
umount /proc
mount -t proc proc /proc
```

And try running apt again.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I think /proc doesn't mount at the end, because if I run `mount -t procproc /proc` and later `umount /proc`, it shows umount: `/proc: not mounted`

Comment: What are you running? Ubuntu 14.04 inside the new Windows 10 "Linux subsystem"?

Comment: Exactly, Ubuntu 14.04 in the W10 linux subsystem

Comment: It is obviously broken, avoid it. If you need to compile Android, Windows is not really the system to do it on. 

Nor is the Linux subsystem, that is more a marketing statement for Windows 10 than anything else.

Comment: I was getting a similar error and this made my problem go away.   
  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu subsystem in Windows is in beta/development, and as an insider you should leave the feedback (where it already exists with three upvotes as i look now) in the Feedback Hub in Windows 10 (it's an app you have installed).

It seems from what i've seen that the /proc filesystem in the ubuntu subsystem is PARTIALLY implemented, and is missing some entries.