# Working in CHROOT environment - Error when trying to install JDK

Tags: java, linux, command-line, installation

I am currently setting up my own Ubuntu 16.04 image for an ARM device (namely an Odroid C1+). Since I want to customize the minimal Ubuntu which works fine, I want to install the package "zookeeperd".

```
sudo apt-get install zookeeperd
```

When doing so the following error appears:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host dualboot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zookeeperd is already the newest version (3.4.8-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20160321) ...
the keytool command requires a mounted proc fs (/proc).
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf depends on ca-certificates-java; however:
  Package ca-certificates-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jre:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zookeeper:
 zookeeper depends on default-jre-headless | java6-runtime-headless; however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf which provides java6-runtime-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zookeeper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zookeeperd:
 zookeeperd depends on zookeeper (= 3.4.8-1); however:
  Package zookeeper is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zookeeperd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre-jamvm:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jre-jamvm:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre-jamvm:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

the keytool command requires a mounted proc fs (/proc).
E: /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with code 1.
done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates-java
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf
 openjdk-8-jre:armhf
 zookeeper
 zookeeperd
 openjdk-8-jre-jamvm:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you experienced the same or have a clue how to resolve the error? Something similar I found was: [Error installing JDK: the keytool command requires a mounted proc fs (/proc). Windows subsystem for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608455/error-installing-jdk-the-keytool-command-requires-a-mounted-proc-fs-proc-wi)
But I want to clarify that I am neither working on the Linux subsystem of Windows 10, nor in a Virtual Machine!

Comment: It looks like your sources file is corrupted. Try these commands:- sudo apt-get clean :

sudo apt-get update:

sudo apt-get upgrade:

sudo apt-get install -f,

Comment: I entered your commands, but when running the upgrade command, the error is here again (tried it both in the current user and the root user). It appeared first when I wanted to install openjdk-8-jre.

Comment: "sudo apt-get --purge remove  zookeeperd" then do "apt-get clean" and "sudo apt-get install -f" and finally reinstall after doing "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: Doesn't work. But a friend of mine got the solution. It's like this one: https://superuser.com/questions/165116/mount-dev-proc-sys-in-a-chroot-environment

Comment: Thanks for helping @skr !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is like this one: https://superuser.com/questions/165116/mount-dev-proc-sys-in-a-chroot-environment

Just do the following:

In host machine:

```
  mount --bind /proc <chroot dir>/proc
```

and another syntax (in chroot environment):

```
  mount -t proc none /proc
```